# Ajax Request and Load Balance

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am experiencing a problem with a page that uses Ajax Requests and is deployed over a Wildfly 8.1.0 Final with JSF 2.2.x

The problem is.  My page has the following excerpt of code, which is the one who has the weird behavior.

```
 <p:outputLabel for="tipoConsulta" id="labelTipoConsulta" value="Tipo de Consulta:  " />
 <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoConsulta"  value="#{mb.tipoConsulta}" label="labelTipoConsulta">
  <f:selectItems value="#{mb.tipoConsultaEnum}" itemLabel="#{text[mb.tipoConsultaEnum]}"/>  
  <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{mb.updateCampos}" update="camposTipoConsulta" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
 <br />
<p:outputPanel id="camposTipoConsulta" style="display:block">
```

So, When I change the value of a dropdown it updates the value of output box (id="camposTipoConsulta").  This works fine in a non clustered environment but when the app is deployed over a clustered environment it does not works.

My guess is because the Ajax Request is being sent to the Load Balance and then the endpoint of the ajax requests happens to not be the same.

I changed the bean associated with this page to SessionScoped (it was ViewedScope before) but did not work.  Any clues?

I am using primefaces 5, jsf 2.2.6, Wildfly 8.1 Final.

Comment: This might be an issue with how load balancing is setup or how clustering is setup for you.  If your cluster isn't configured for shared sessions then if the requests goes to another server than the one your session was initialized with then the session will not exist.  If shared sessions isn't possible for your cluster then your load balancer needs to be set for sticky sessions where it always delegates to the same server for a single session and only balances load for anonymous and new session requests.

Comment: Stick Sessions did not work. :(
I will try the Shared Session approach.

Comment: Nothing worked so far.  There is a problem with the SessionMap.  A programmer that is working to solve this issue plugged the remote debugger into an instance of the cluster and when I do a request it goes to the monitored instance as expected, but my next ajax request that produces the wierd behaviour goes to the other instance.

The environment is using mod_jk with stick sessions enabled as well.  And we changed our bean to session scoped annotation.

Even so, the problem remains the same.
Now listening Led Zepplin :)

Comment: That is strange. Did you look at the HTTP request header of the Ajax request to make sure the session id is passed in the header?  Firebug is good for this.

Comment: JSessionID changes from cluster instance to cluster instance, indicating that the Stick Session is not working although it is configured in JBoss clusteres and Tomcat mod_jk load balance.

Comment: That sounds like you have your answer right there.  You either have JBoss or mod_jk not configured correctly.